# How can i read file name of utf8 encodng in euc-kr encoding system using java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I use euc-kr encoding system.
My program made by Java.
It read file name.
But the program can not read some files name.
(some files name is utf8 encoding)

so I tried this

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] fileList = dir.listFiles(); //get files that file name is utf8 encoding
String cangedEncodingstr= new String(fileList[0].getName().getBytes("euc-kr"), "euc-kr"); // This is still an invalid string
```

.

I think that this string is already broken during call `dir.listFiles()`

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] fileList = dir.listFiles(); //get files that file name is utf8 encoding

fileList[0].getName(); // broken String
fileList[0].isFile(); //false
fileList[0].isDirectory(); //false
```

The string in utf8 encoding also expects `isFile ()` to be true.

Thanks in advance for your reply.   :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`File.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()) returns a `String`. So, you don't have to do anything more in Java.

A `String` in Java is a text-only datatype. It contains a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units—that is, a counted sequence of `char`. Every string function is written based on this. You generally don't need to account for that because much of text processing doesn't depend on it. The few times that it does are when you are counting or splitting on indexes that aren't obtained from indexOf or similar text functions.

Many languages are likes this, such as .NET languages, VB4/5/6/A/Script, JavaScript, SQL NVARCHAR or NCHAR. Others have "strings" that really just byte strings, which might be text with one of many encodings, such as Lua, C, C++, …. Others have different types of strings that keep a difference between a byte string and a character string, such as Python. Others have strings that include an attribute to indicate the character encoding of a character string, such as R.